# Could anyone explain what he is doing in this video?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I found a video on Youtube where someone did that same thing that i want to do, but this video has no commentary so I don't know how to follow along. Could anyone explain to me what the Person in this Video is doing at min 02:00.

Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3481ueuDJwQ
[image]
Thank You!

Comment: He just added a mirror modifier and then started extruding. If you are new I would recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs&t=867s

Comment: Why not ask the person who made the video? If their video is unclear and you let them know, both of you can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're talking about his use of the "mirror" modifier. At exactly 2:00, he checked the "clipping" box. What this does is it restricts edits to the object that would extend it past a line drawn through the origin point, perpendicular to the mirrored axis. For example:

[image]

"Clipping" prevents me from moving the selected edge past the origin point along the X-axis.

Without clipping, this would be possible:

[image]

For more, see this [video on the mirror modifier](https://youtu.be/3LwQO_tWTAQ?t=7m57s).